# css script vs datatable script

Tags: css, datatable, show

is my datatable not show because of css code?

```
<html>
<head> 
   <title>OQC INSPECTION REPORT</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
   <link href="js/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
           body      { font-family: Verdana; font-size:40%; }
           label { width: 15em; float: left; }
           label.error {display: none; float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
           p { clear: both; }
           .submit { margin-left: 12em; }
           em { font-weight: bold; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
     </style>

     <style type="text/css">
           body
           {
             font-family:Times new roman, verdana;
             font-size:22px;
             width: 900px;
             height:70px;
             margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
             background-image:url("wood_texture2.jpg");
           }
     </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    var oTable;
                    $("#show").click(function(event){
                                    oTable = $("#datalist").dataTable({
                                                    "bRetrieve"  : true,
                                                    "bServerSide": true,
                                                    "bProcessing": true,
                                                    "sAjaxSource": 'showlist1.php',
                                                    "aaSorting"  : [[1,"desc"]],
                                                    "aoColumns"  : [
                                                                    /*Line*/  null,
                                                                    /*Model*/ null,
                                                                    /*NIK*/   null
                                                                    ]
                                            });
                                   });
                       });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get rid of the css and see if it still works.

Comment: I don't know what the 'datagrid' is. There doesn't seem to be anything in the css that would cause a visible grid. I'm thinking here of border and/or outline properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS has nothing to do with it, unless I overlooked something.

It would be helpful if you showed your HTML as well.

I suggest debugging with Firebug.

---

EDIT

If that is in fact your whole page, your problem is you have **NO HTML elements** on it. You need several -- I would reread the documentation.

Comment: i've been using firebug and it show the result but datatable not show

Comment: I don't see the difference and my answer still applies.